# Confluent Cloud Private Connectivity (Azure) with multiple Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, openshift, confluent-platform

We are in a situation where we need to connect with
Confluent Kafka cluster (which is on Microsoft Azure Cloud) using Microsoft Private Link.

We were able to connect using Private Link and Private End point with our MS Azure VNet (subnet). But we also have third party reading/consuming (Source/Sink) data directly from Confluent Cluster directly.

It is required that the connection of the third party with Confluent Cluster must also be on a private network. How can we ensure that? (Third party is using Openshift on MS Azure)?

Comment: It's not at all clear what your question is here. [ask]

Comment: I have tried to elaborate the question again; not sure if that is cleared enough now.